# cancan accessible_by w/ mongoid criteria syntax

Tags: mongoid, cancan

i have an ability defined with mongoid criteria, that is not populating the mongoid criteria selector.

```
can :manage, Number, :issuer_id.in => user.owner_of.map{ |p| p.id }
```

returns

```
-> Number.accessible_by(Ability.new(user))
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {},
  options:  {},
  class:    Number,
  embedded: false>
```

if i query mongoid directly with the same criteria

```
-> Number.where(:issuer_id.in => user.owner_of.map{ |p| p.id })
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {:issuer_id=>{"$in"=>[BSON::ObjectId('4f9ae0f1e1607c7a67000002')]}},
  options:  {},
  class:    Number,
  embedded: false>
```

ability instance returns...

```
-> Ability.new(user)
=> #<Ability:0x007f8c9d0c1030 @rules=[
     #<CanCan::Rule:0x007f8c9a5b0210
       @match_all=false,
       @base_behavior=true,
       @actions=[:manage],
       @subjects=[Number],
       @conditions={issuer_id=>[BSON::ObjectId('4f9ae0f1e1607c7a67000002')]},
       @block=nil
     >
   ]>
```

i have tried defining my abilities a variety of ways

```
can :manage, Number, :issuer => { :owner_id => user.id }
can :manage, Number, :issuer_id.in => user.owner_of.map{ |p| p.id }
can :manage, Number, :issuer_id => { "$in" => user.owner_of.map{ |p| p.id }}
```

Answer (score 2):

solved it. `user.owner_of.map{ |p| p.id }` was returning an array of BSON objects. i needed an array of strings. `user.owner_of.map{ |p| p.id.to_s }` solved it. gah!